# jaccard_similarity_score raises ValueError: continuous-multioutput is not supported

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cluster-analysis, k-means

I would like to compute similarity between clusters, producted by using KMeans, using Jaccard index (from sklearn.metrics import jaccard_similarity_score). These may be a matrix which contains specific values: at [i,j] should be similarity between cluster i and j. My code for now:

```
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
from sklearn.metrics import jaccard_similarity_score
iris = datasets.load_iris()
X = iris.data
kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=3).fit(X)
labels = kmeans.labels_

for i in range(3):
        for j in range(3):
            print(jaccard_similarity_score(X[np.where(labels==i)], X[np.where(labels==j)]))
```

But I've got the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-15-e7b8e4471987>", line 3, in <module>
    print(jaccard_similarity_score(X[np.where(labels==i)], X[np.where(labels==j)]))

  File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\p3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\metrics\classification.py", line 383, in jaccard_similarity_score
    y_type, y_true, y_pred = _check_targets(y_true, y_pred)

  File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\p3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\metrics\classification.py", line 89, in _check_targets
    raise ValueError("{0} is not supported".format(y_type))

ValueError: continuous-multioutput is not supported
```

Comment: What does the two for loops for i and j do? Why is jaccard_similarity score called from within the loop?

Comment: Because I wanted to compute jaccard index for each pair of clusters. These records should be actually input into matrix[i][j]

Answer (score 0):

Jaccard is defined on *sets*.

K-means produces *continuous* centroids (because it is using the *mean*, literally).

Hence, you cannot use Jaccard on the cluster centers.